InvalidOperationException for GraphQL 7.8.0 in C#
I'm getting the following exception when I run my code (my target framework is currently .NET 6.0):

Exception Occured: System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1[System.Char]' of property 'Span' on type 'GraphQLParser.ROM' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.

I'm using graphql 8.0.0, GraphQL-Parser 9.5.0, GraphQL.NewtonsoftJson 8.0.0 and GraphQL.SystemTextJson 8.0.0
The only place where the ROM class is used in my project is within the DateGraphType class - the code is shown below:
private static DateTime ParseDate(ROM stringValue)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
#if NETSTANDARD2_0
        (string)
#endif
        stringValue, "yyyy-MM-dd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out var date))
    {
        return date;
    }

    throw new FormatException($"Could not parse date. Expected yyyy-MM-dd. Value: {stringValue}");
}

This exception is happening when I attempt to query my database - I don't get an exception when doing the call - the exception is happening after my database query request is completed
Any ideas on how can I get rid of this exception?
I tried to adjust the graphql libraries to 7.8.0 and the graphql-parser to 8.4.2 - this did not work
---- stack trace --
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_CannotSerializeInvalidType(Type typeToConvert, Type declaringType, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.ReflectionJsonTypeInfo`1.CreateProperty(Type typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Boolean shouldCheckForRequiredKeyword)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.ReflectionJsonTypeInfo`1.CacheMember(Type typeToConvert, MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean& propertyOrderSpecified, Dictionary`2& ignoredMembers, Boolean shouldCheckForRequiredKeyword)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.ReflectionJsonTypeInfo`1.LateAddProperties()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.InitializePropertyCache()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.Configure()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureLocked|143_0()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureLocked|143_0()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.EnsureConfigured()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo.get_JsonTypeInfo()
   at System.Text.Json.WriteStackFrame.GetNestedJsonTypeInfo()
   at System.Text.Json.WriteStack.Push()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ArrayConverter`2.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TElement[] array, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWriteAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
enter code here


Show us the full stack-trace of the exception.

Does stringValue.ToString() work?

ok @Dai - i added the full stack trace
